# Excel Automation Performance of VB6 client application versus C# client application

Tags: c#, performance, excel, vb6, automation

I've invested a lot of time in converting some old VB6 / *.xla code into a C# application and now have come to find that I've dug myself into a major performance hole.  It seems that automating Excel from C# (VS 2010) has some sort of major performance impact.  I've written the 'exact' code in a test VB6 application and get calculations running in about 1-2 seconds.  Where as the code in C# takes over a minute.  The general flow of the code is like this…(where Client is either VB6 or C# application).

**-- Only done once for lifetime of client application**

1. Client creates and opens and Excel Application
2. Client automates Excel to load required add-ins needed for calculations.

   **-- Done for each calculation performed**
3. Client automates Excel to close any existing *.xls file and open the desired *.xls file.
4. Client calls macro from Excel add in using ExcelAppObject.Run( "AddIn.xla!GetConfiguration" ) to get the configuration of *.xls opened in step 3.
5. Client calls macro from Excel add in using ExcelAppObject.Run( "AddIn.xla!LoadInputs", InputsXmlString )

   1. The macro loads InputsXmlString into MSXML.DOMDocument40 object.
   2. **The macro turns Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual (to speed up populating several 'tables' of inputs)**
   3. The macro sets Application.EnableEvents = false
   4. The macro loops all 'configured' inputs/tables on the 'Input' worksheet and clears them (in case the passed in xml doesn't contain 'all' inputs)
   5. The macro loops all xml passed in and loads into appropriate locations on the 'Input' worksheet.
6. Client calls macro from Excel add in using ExcelAppObject.Run( "AddIn.xla!GetResults", DataXmlString )

   1. The macro loads DataXmlString into MSXML.DOMDocument40 object.
   2. The macro loops all 'configured' data values on the 'Input' worksheet and clears them (in case the passed in xml doesn't contain 'all' data or clearing out previous calculation)
      This is different from LoadInputs because we could have a batch calculation where inputs are same for every calculation but the 'participant data' obviously is different for each calculation
   3. The macro loads all the data from DataXmlString into appropriate locations on 'Input' worksheet
   4. The macro sets Application.EnableEvents = true
   5. **The macro turns Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic (to make sure calculation occurs now that all data/inputs have been loaded)**
   6. The macro loops all the configured 'result cells' and returns them via Xml string.

So as you can see, for each calculation, I only have three 'cross process' calls from client to Excel (GetConfiguration, LoadInputs, and GetResults) to try and minimize that known 'poor' performance issue.  The problem is, when the exact same code is called from a VB6 application steps 4-6 take about 2 seconds.  When the client application is a C# application, 4-6 take about 70 seconds.  *All* of this 70 seconds occurs on step 6 when I turn calculation back to Automatic.

Is there a known issue with C# applications automating Excel versus legacy VB6 applications and/or are there any proposed work arounds so that I can keep my C# code but somehow achieve the same performance as VB6?

Comment: Try building your application in Release mode and running it outside of Visual Studio.

Comment: We are/have built in release.  Then to start debugging and finding problems, we are now testing in LINQPad with a 'simpler' more direct script instead of our entire 'broker' code/framework.

Comment: So you have tried running it without any debugger attached whatsoever?

Answer (score 0):

Using C# to interact with Excel through COM Interop is generally extremely poor from a performance point of view: 
I would suggest that if you want to continue with C# you look at Excel DNA or Addin Express, both of which enable you to use the much faster XLL interace from C#.
See http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/excel-udf-technology-choices-snakes-ladders-with-vba-vb6-net-c-com-xll-interop/
for my brief evaluation of the currently available technology choices for interacing with Excel.

The main performance bottleneck with C# is usually transferring dat from Excel to C#: each data transfer call acrries a large overhead, so its usually much faster to transfer large blocks of data using an array.

Comment: Think you may have missed my main issue.  I've minimized the calls from C# to Excel to 'three'.  But the simple act of turning Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic (within Excel/VBA) when the calling client *was* C#, caused an extremely big differential in performance as opposed to when the client is VB6.  I understand that multiple calls from client to Excel (regardless of VB6 or C#) is bad, which is why I've got it down to a minimum.

Comment: Charles - I read up on your product.  I'm not sure if/how it would help out our calculations, however my company is not the 'owner' of the Spreadsheets.  Other 'developers' provide them to us so we would be required to have them update all the spreadsheets for the different clients.  So I'm reading up again trying to grasp exactly what it is that your product might provide and see if the benefit is worth the effort needed to do all the conversions.

Comment: Terry: I am confused - has your actual calculation time increased (step 5, in which case are you using c# UDFs?) or the time taken to read the results of the calculation (step 6, Looping the result cells sounds like reading them one-by-one)?

Comment: Not using any C# UDFs.  C# calls three vba UDFs (GetConfiguration, LoadInputs, GetResults).  Inside the vba UDFs is where any/all looping and cell/range access occurs.  Basically C# packages up an Xml string of instructions and sends to vba UDF, it in turn returns back an Xml string of 'results'.  But when called from C#, the behavior of one line inside the udf (Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic) behaves differently.  When client is VB6 it is immediate.  When client is C#, it takes 60 seconds.  Beyond frustrating and beyond baffling.

Comment: Now I am even more confused - we must be using different terminology. A UDF is a function written in some language (VBA, c# ...) that is called from a worksheet cell. Application.Calculate has no effect within a UDF because the UDF is called FROM a calculation.

Comment: That's what I mostly thought.  I misread your comment above.  I thought you asked if I was using any C# UDFs.  So, there are probably some UDFs defined in the VBA (either the actual spreadsheet or loaded add-ins).  I'm not sure how many cells use those functions.  But the flow from my previous comment still holds true regarding how I have 'minimal' calls from client to Excel automation and pass all information needed in an Xml blob.

Comment: My application only transfer data from C# to Excel. In details, read data from text file (which is like 30MB in size) from C# and write the data to Excel. It takes extremely long. Is this still the same issue?